# Advantages of using keys() function when iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python

Is there any advantage to using keys() function?

```
for word in dictionary.keys():
    print word
```

vs

```
for word in dictionary:
    print word
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in Python 2.x iterating directly over the dictionary saves some memory, as the keys list isn't duplicated.

You could also use `.iterkeys()`, or in Python 2.7, use `.viewkeys()`.

In Python 3.x, `.keys()` is a view, and there is no difference.

So, in conclusion: use `d.keys()` (or `list(d.keys())` in python 3) only if you *need* a copy of the keys, such as when you'll change the dict in the loop. Otherwise iterate over the dict directly.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `key in d` is considered more idiomatic (and certainly neater on the page) than `key in d.keys()` or `key in d.iterkeys()`.